# Simple find primes implementation

Tags: c#

i have idea "find primes between 1 and n".
    Algorithms based on residual division.
    i use 2 array pr and nt.
    [pr is saved primes. nt is saved counter number.]
    ex.
    begin with 3
    3 is primes => pr0 = 3 and nt0 = 2.
    primes >3 is odd.
    when i = 5 nt0 = nt0-1 = 1  => 5 is prime.
    And pr1 = 5, nt1 =pr1 -1 = 4.
    when i = 7 :
    nt0 = nt0 -1 = 0, => 7 is prime.
    and pr2 = 7, nt2 = 6.
    when i = 9
    nt0 < 0 => 9 is not prime. nt0 = pr0 -1 = 2, nt1 = 3, nt2 = 5.
    ....

```
    using System;
    namespace primes
    { // program for find primes between 1 and n.
    class Program
    {    public  static void Main()
        {           
            int[] pr = new int[100], ct = new int[100];             
            ct[0] = 2;
            pr[0] = 3;// 3 is primes => n[0] is 3 . 
            int n = 1; // n is number of primes.
            for (int i = 5; i < 111; i += 2)
            {               
                for (int l = 0; l < n; l++)
                { if (ct[l] >= 0)
                    {
                       ct[l]--  ;
                        //Console.Write("{0} ", ct[l]);                     
                    }                    
                  else
                    {
                        ct[l] = pr[l] - 1  ;
                     //  Console.Write("{0} ", ct[l]);
                        for (int a = l + 1; a < n; a++)
                        {
                            ct[a]--;
                         //   Console.Write("{0} ", ct[a]);
                        }
                    //    Console.WriteLine();
                        goto resume; // when ct <0 jump to resume
                    }                
                }
           //     Console.WriteLine();
                pr[n] = i;
                ct[n] = i ;                
            //    Console.Write("{0} ", ct[n]);
                n++;
            resume : ;
            }
            for (int m = 0; m < n; m++)
            {
                Console.Write(" {0}", pr[m]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();            
        }
    }  
    }
```

i want to print primes 3,5,7,11, 13...
but i when i run:  3 5 7 9 13 15 17 23 29 37 39 63 65 71 89.
i dont understand. 
Can you help me?

Comment: Help you how? Is something going wrong? If so, what?

Comment: How do you expect to receive support if you won't even put in the effort to explain what's happening?

Comment: Is this a question or just a bunch of code?

Comment: **Never** use `goto`. There are loops for example that achieve the same in a far more readable way - or in your case a simple `break` would do it.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Oh wow, I hadn't spotted that, haven't seen a `goto` in the wild for such a long time!

Comment: @Nguyen You edited your post but you still haven't asked a question!

Comment: i want to primt primes : 3,5,7,11,13...          but   3 5 7 9 13 15 17 23 29 37 39 63 65 71 89. i dont understand

Comment: I didn't think c# actually supports goto.

Comment: @Hirasawa Yui, [yes it does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto).

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Can be easily replaced by `continue` in this case. And is evil in every case :-)

Answer (score 0):

i was wrong when used

```
 if (ct[l] >= 0)
                    {
                       ct[l]--  ;
                        //Console.Write("{0} ", ct[l]);                     
                    }                    
                  else {
.... goto resume ;
}
```

"when ct[l] < 0 and ct[k]<0(k>l) =>  ct[l] = pr[l] -1.
 But ct[k] = ct[k] -1."

```
 if(v != 0)
                { v = 0;// =>i is not prime and v = 0.
                }
               else  { 
                pr[n] = i;// =>i is prime
                ct[n] = i-1 ;          
                n++;
```

Answer (score -1):

thanks all. 
i finished my program.
This is my code :

```
using System;

namespace primes
{ // program for find primes between 1 and n.
    class Program
    {    public  static void Main()
        {           
            int[] pr = new int[100], ct = new int[100];             
            ct[0] = 2;
            pr[0] = 3;// 3 is primes => n[0] is 3 . 
            int n = 1;
            int v = 0;
            for (int i = 5; i < 111; i += 2)
            {               
                for (int l = 0; l < n; l++)
                { if (ct[l] == 0)
                    {
                        ct[l] = pr[l] - 1;
                        v++;                                       
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ct[l]--;                        
                    }                        
                }    
                if(v != 0)
                { v = 0;
                }
               else  { 
                pr[n] = i;
                ct[n] = i-1 ;          
                n++;
            }

            }
            for (int m = 0; m < n; m++)
            {
                Console.Write(" {0}", pr[m]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();            
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you changed?  This isn't going to be helpful for anyone else as-is.